# Program crashes when trying to run a specific part of my code

Tags: c

My code goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

char ** djiksin(char ** inp){

}
int evaluation(char ** rpn){

}
void printarr(char arr[]){
    int i=0;
    while(arr[i] != '\0'){
        printf("%c",arr[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
int main(){
    int i = 0,k = 0,j=0;
    char a[201] = {'\0'};
    char ** strinp;
    fgets(a,201,stdin);
    while(a[i] != '\0'){
        if(a[i] == '(' || a[i] == ')' || a[i] == '*'|| a[i] == '+'|| a[i] == '^'|| a[i] == '~'|| a[i] == '/'|| a[i] == '-'){
            j = 0;
            k = k+1;
            strinp[k][j] = a[i];
            k = k + 1;
        }else if(a[i] == ' '){
            k = k + 1;
            j = 0;
        }else{
            strinp[k][j] = a[i];
            j = j+1;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    printarr(a);
    return 0;
 }
```

Purpose of the code so far is to take a mathmethical formula and format it for the use of the shunting yard alghorithm. which in my mind is trying to get every operator and operand in seperate strings. 
In the end strinp should give an array of strings which i can use in my previously declared functions.

But every time i try to compile&run the program for testing after i put in the input windows gives the error "Program stopped working". After closing the error it outputs this on the command prompt: `Process exited after 3.871 seconds with return value 3221225477`

And when i comment the `while` section in `main` the code works just fine with the proper output.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Simplest solution is making striinp  a 2-D  array.  Something like strinp[100][201].

Answer (score 1):

```
char ** strinp;
...
strinp[k][j] = a[i];
```

`strinp` is an uninitialized pointer. You haven't allocated any memory for it, and you don't have it pointing to useful memory. Dereferencing an invalid pointer is the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You don't allocate memory for your strinp variable.

```
char ** strinp = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 20);

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    strinp[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
}
```

What you need is something like this. Of course you need to change the allocation size according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As other guys said you must allocate Memory before any attempt to assign value to srtinp pionter.

```
/*

compile ::: $ gcc test.c -o test

run :::    $ ./test

*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


void
printarr(char arr[])
{ 
    int i=0;
    while(arr[i] != '\0'){
        printf("%c",arr[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}


int 
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0,k = 0,j=0;
    char a[201] = {'\0'};
    char ** strinp;

    printf("Enter a string\n");
    fgets(a,201,stdin);///get input from user


/// obtain length of input 
    int x=-1;
    for (x=0 ; a[x]!='\0' && x<=200;x++){
            ;
    }
    x--;

    printf("lenght of a: %d\n",x);///len a is x



/// allocate sufficient amount of Memory
strinp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * x);
for(int i=0;i<x; i++) 
  strinp[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*x);  




//~ i=0;
//~ j=0;
//~ k=0;

    /// do this 
    ///seem to erase space from input
    while(a[i+1] != '\0'){
        //printf("in while1\n");
        if(a[i] == '(' || a[i] == ')' || a[i] == '*'|| a[i] == '+'|| a[i] == '^'|| a[i] == '~'|| a[i] == '/'|| a[i] == '-'){
            j = 0;
            k = k+1;
            //printf("in while2\n");
            strinp[k][j] = a[i];
            //printf("%c,%c\n",a[i],strinp[k][j]);
            k = k + 1;
            //printf("%c\n",a[i]);
        }else if(a[i] == ' '){
            k = k + 1;
            j = 0;
           // printf("%c\n",a[i]);
        }else{///if alphabet or number
            //printf("in while 3\n");
            strinp[k][j] = a[i];
            //printf("%c,%c\n",a[i],strinp[k][j]);
            j = j+1;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    printf("array:");
    printarr(a);///print array of a[]
    //printf("end\n");

    ///print strinp 
    printf("pointer:");
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
     for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
        printf("%c",strinp[i][j]);

    printf("\n");       

    ///free aloocated memory
    for(i=0;i<x; i++) 
        free(strinp[i]);
    free(strinp);

    return 0;

}
```